# Capture and export triangulated position from Android phone

Tags: android, geolocation

I'd like to automatically collect the triangulated position (not GPS) from my Android cell phone. I was wondering if anyone knew of any existing code to do something like this to get me started? If not, any pointers as to how to write this code myself would be greatly appreciated (though I should mention that I've never done any android development before, so please provide plenty of details if possible).

By 'triangulated position', I mean the location and radius of uncertainty provided on Google Maps when the GPS is not enabled. What I'd like, is to be able to write the position (and radius) to a file every ~10seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for the [network location provider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER)